# Is there a way to query for the account balances of a NEAR account over time or other advanced datasets?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

What services or APIs are available to do advanced queries of account state on NEAR Protocol?  The most basic is a time series of account balances for a specific account over time, eg:

```
# for account foo.near
20220731  1.234
20220730  1.567
...
```

I know Flipside has indexed the chain ([docs](https://docs.metricsdao.xyz/data-curation/near)) and [stats.gallery](https://stats.gallery/) does account-level stuff with charts but I can't find any dashboards that display this on [awesomenear.com](https://awesomenear.com/categories/analytics) or good APIs. Any others?

Ideally there are more advanced queries possible as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

https://pikespeak.ai/ is nice & an API is on their roadmap. It doesn't give you balance on every block but there is CSV export so it can be added in an xls/sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Enhanced APIs are available to use to get all kinds of balances on NFTs, FTs and NEAR! Access them via Pagoda Console
https://console.pagoda.co/